# PTIJ: Can my friend be eaten?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

My Hebrew is far short of what I would like, so I often must rely on translation. In the translation I read:

> Every moving thing that liveth shall be meat for you; even as the green herb have I given you all things.

My friend Herb has just started a new career, and is considered very green. Is it lawful to eat him? Are only co-workers allowed this, seeing as he is green only to them?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Done. Kinda green myself.

Comment: It seems that this pasuk permits eating anything that moves, so even if his name wasn't Herb and he wasn't green, I don't see the issue

Comment: True, as this was before Moshe's time. But a subsequent passage does require that he not be strangled.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100646/1569

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50901/cannibalism-jew-or-gentile